# Wordpress problem: The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor, storefront

I am in trouble with Wordpress. I am developing an ecommerce site and I am doing it locally. The site is not hosted anywhere in the internet. I am using Storefront theme. I was following a tutorial to fix a problem with Elementor plugin and when I enabled in elementor tools the safe mode my site stopped working. I got this message "The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions " and I don´t know how fix it. All the tutorials I found in the internet was using the cPanel but I don´t have any.... Can anyone help me?? Thanks!!

Comment: Add `define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE);` to your wp-config.php. That will hopefully give you an error. You can also check local server logs. Disable Elementor by renaming the plugin folder and reload your site.